# How do I setup SoapUI to have a REST service using a "Template" style parameter, which is comma delimited 1 or more times?

Tags: rest, parameters, soapui

I'm using SoapUI's REST service to do some testing. See this link for an example of the Template parameter: http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html

My request needs to look like this:

```
http://www.myservice.com/endpoint/parameter1/parameter2a,parameter2b/parameter3
```

How can I make the template style parameter occur >=1 times for the "parameter2" part of the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `${#TestCase#Parameter2}` as the default value and build up the string with a Groovy Script and set the Property with something like :

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "Parameter2", "p2a,p2b,p3c" )
```